# Trying to check if a request header includes a certain ip

Tags: varnish-vcl, varnish-4

I am trying to check if a request header includes a certain ip, but using the matching operator `~` is not working as expected:

```
if (req.http.X-Forwarded-For && req.http.X-Forwarded-For ~ "^.*" + server.ip + ".*$") {
    # logic
}
```

I get the error:

> Error:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            │
> │ Message from VCC-compiler:                                                                                                                                                                                                                        │
> │ Expected ')' got '+'                                                                                                                                                                                                                              │
> │ (program line 68), at                                                                                                                                                                                                                             │
> │ ('/tmp/vcl' Line 300 Pos 74)                                                                                                                                                                                                                      │
> │         if (req.http.X-Forwarded-For && req.http.X-Forwarded-For ~ "^.*" + server.ip + ".*$") {

Any ideas why that is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hum.. server.ip is an IP address, not a string
The following code might do the trick

```
  if (std.strstr(req.http.X-Forwarded-For, server.ip) != "") {
    # logic
  }
```